# Akka Streams' ActorPublisher as a Source for web response - how back-pressure works

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, akka-stream, backpressure

I use *akka-streams*' `ActorPublisher` actor as a streaming per-connection `Source` of data being sent to an incoming WebSocket or HTTP connection.

`ActorPublisher`'s [contract](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/actor/ActorPublisher.scala#L100) is to regularly request data by supplying a *demand* - number of elements that can be accepted by downstream. I am not supposed to send more elements if the demand is 0. I observe that if I buffer elements, when consumer is slow, that buffer size fluctuates between 1 and 60, but mostly near 40-50.

To stream I use *akka-http*'s ability to set WebSocket output and `HttpResponse` data to a `Source` of `Message`s (or `ByteString`s).

I wonder how the back-pressure works in this case - when I'm streaming data to a client through network. How exactly these numbers are calculated? Does it check what's happening on network level?

Comment: I *think* that akka-streams I/O layer delegates to TCP backpressure, but I don't have proof - the I/O code there is too hard for me to decipher :(

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could find for your question "how the back-pressure works in this case" is from [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html#implications-of-the-streaming-nature-of-request-response-entities):

> Akka HTTP is streaming all the way through, which means that the
>   back-pressure mechanisms enabled by Akka Streams are exposed through
>   all layers–from the TCP layer, through the HTTP server, all the way up
>   to the user-facing HttpRequest and HttpResponse and their HttpEntity
>   APIs.

As to "how these numbers are calculated", I believe that is [specified in the configuration settings](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/general/stream/stream-configuration.html).